# Different results using awk gensub in script

Tags: shell, awk

In my attempt to flip a character string with two parts separated by a space, I found two different results depending on how it's done.

Method 1 :

```
echo "ABCD EFGH" | awk '{print gensub ( /( .+ ) ( .+ )/, "\\2 \\1", "g", $0 ) 
}'
> ABCD EFGH #no flip (not desired resutls)
```

Method 2 :

```
cat > temp.sh
awk 'BEGIN {xx = "ABCD EFGH"
            xx_ = gensub(/(.+) (.+)/, "\\2 \\1", "g", xx)
            print xx_
            }'
sh temp.sh
> EFGH ABCD  ## desired results
```

What gives? What do I need to fix in method 1? Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't you recognize an obvious typo in your first command of having extra spaces in your regex match?

```
echo "ABCD EFGH" | awk '{print gensub ( /( .+ ) ( .+ )/, "\\2 \\1", "g", $0 ) }'
#                                         ^  ^   ^  ^ incorrect spaces defined
```

It should have been defined as below. Also you don't need to put `$0` in the last argument, as it is understood and optional to do, i.e. if `$0` is not mentioned explicitly, the operation by default takes on the whole `$0`.

```
echo "ABCD EFGH" | awk '{print gensub ( /(.+) (.+)/, "\\2 \\1", "g") }'
```

Comment: Oops. You are right Indeed. My actually codes was much longer. The spaces were added when I copied and paste to create an excerpt to be used as MWE. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

You've already got an explanation as to why your regex doesn't work. So I'll just point out that you're writing in GNU awk, and `gensub()` doesn't exist in most other awks.

So instead, for portability, I'll propose that you reverse your fields a different way:

```
$ echo "ABCD EFGH" | awk '{for(i=NF;i;i--) o=o OFS $i; print substr(o,length(OFS)+1)}'
```

This steps through your fields in reverse order and appends them to a variable, separated by your output field separator. It then prints the variable, stripping OFS as it goes. It also works with more than 2 fields.

Comment: Since my actual task is a bit different from my naive MWE above, I am working on posting another question. Your approach is much appreciated with the use of substr. Very nice ! Thank you !